# How can I manipulate the query and masking type from the client and return the appropriate masking to the client?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have sensitive data and I want to do masking on accessing this sensitive data. I want to mask the sensitive data by manipulating the query from the client and return the client in response.

For Example

Client query:

```
select * from [users]

name: Half Mask
surname : Half Mask
age : Random Number
identification_number : Middle Mask
```

And this is the example of real data for [users]:

```
id      name        surname    age  identification_number   phone_number           address
300024  Trever      Wilkinson   48       00154974867        1-463-842-2419         0865 Nicolette Falls, Dannyside, Qatar
300025  Crawford    Considine   61       44019179776        1-315-914-7507         2436 Legros Flats, Robinmouth, Guadeloupe
300026  Cassie      Upton       70       86767454256        490.711.7746 314       1571 Cierra Meadow, Halvorsonview, American Samoa
300027  Holden      Hessel      25       10618804336        1-700-986-7306 7718    6349 Ebert Centers, North Kathlyn, Slovakia (Slovak Republic)
```

But I want to response the client like this data:

```
id      name   surname   age    identification_number   phone_number         address
300024  T***   W***      0        0********7            1-463-842-2419       0865 Nicolette Falls, Dannyside, Qatar
300025  C***   C***      0        4********6            1-315-914-7507       2436 Legros Flats, Robinmouth, Guadeloupe
300026  C***   U***      0        8********6            490.711.7746 314     1571 Cierra Meadow, Halvorsonview, American Samoa
300027  H***   H**       0        1********6            1-700-986-7306 7718  6349 Ebert Centers, North Kathlyn, Slovakia (Slovak Republic)
```

Comment: I guess, you can create a view with all required masking and then in the client perform select from this view. Or you can also use SQL Server's datamasking functionality

Comment: Do not give direct access to sensitive data. If you want them to be able to write queries, have them query against a _view_ that already either doesn't show the cols or only masked values.

Comment: You are asking for *Dynamic Data Masking* - surely you found that from your very first Google search on the subject.

Comment: I saw Dynamic Data Masking while researching on the internet, but I'm actually looking for masking variety. In other words, I want to ensure that different types of masking are selected in the project I will create. For example, I want to apply full masking for some queries and half masking for some queries. Or I just want to mask a certain character in the data. I didn't see this variation in dynamic data masking.

Comment: There's a massive amount of detail missing from this question. Tell us how your user even runs the query in the first place, how they see the results etc. The only clue is "returned to the client" - leads me to believe that you accept some SQL in an API call and want to star out swathes of JSON going back..

Comment: I'm planning to create a service between sql server and client on the C# side.

Comment: And I'm asking, is it possible to mask in this structure?